# multiple UIScrollViews on a UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

Is there any way to add multiple `UIScrollView`'s on a single `UIView`?

I made the `UIView` 2 parts. On the first part of view, I want to add one `UIScrollView`, and on the other, I want to add a second scrollview. The problem I'm facing is when I'm trying to zoom on the first, the second scroll is also responding.

How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 3):

You should differentiate your scroll view by its `tag` property. Like :

assign tag to your scroll views

```
scrollView1.tag = 2001;
scrollView2.tag = 3001;
```

And then

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)myScrollView
{

    if (myScrollView.tag == 2001) 
    {
        //do stuff with scrollView1
    } 
    else if (myScrollView.tag == 3001) 
    {
        //do stuff with scrollView2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this Delegate method:-

Delegate methods send with it the object that sent the message (the UIScrollView in this case). So, all you have to do is check that against your instance variables of scrollView1 and scrollView2.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)myScrollView {

    if (myScrollView == scrollView1) {
        //do stuff with scrollView1
    } else if (myScrollView == scrollView2) {
        //do stuff with scrollView2
    }
}
```